# Sending email from php, through exchange

Tags: php, email, exchange-server

I need to send mails from php via an Exchange box. I've been given ip, account and password. Are there standard libs to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: This is a poor answer. Please explain in detail how the user could use PHPMailer to do what this person asks.